# how can I fetch only inner fields from source in ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-dsl

I have index structure like this:

```
{
          "id" : 42,
          "Person" : {
            "contracts" : [
              {
                "contractID" : "000000000000102"
              }
            ],
            "Ids" : [
              3,
              387,
              100,
              500,
              274,
              283,
              328,
              400,
              600
            ]
          },
          "dateUpdate" : "2020-12-07T13:15:00.408Z"
        }
      },
      ...
}
```

I need a search query that will fetch only inner "Ids" field from source and nothing more. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `_source` in `inner_hits`, in the following way

**Index Mapping:**

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "Person": {
        "type": "nested"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "Person",
            "query": {
              "match_all": {}
            },
            "inner_hits": {
              "_source": {
                "includes": [
                  "Person.Ids"
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"inner_hits": {
          "Person": {
            "hits": {
              "total": {
                "value": 1,
                "relation": "eq"
              },
              "max_score": 1.0,
              "hits": [
                {
                  "_index": "65237264",
                  "_type": "_doc",
                  "_id": "1",
                  "_nested": {
                    "field": "Person",
                    "offset": 0
                  },
                  "_score": 1.0,
                  "_source": {
                    "Ids": [
                      3,
                      387,
                      100,
                      500,
                      274,
                      283,
                      328,
                      400,
                      600
                    ]
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
```

You can also use [nested `inner_hits` and `_souce`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/search-request-inner-hits.html#nested-inner-hits-source), in the following way

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "Person",
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "inner_hits": {
        "_source" : false,
        "docvalue_fields" : [
          {
            "field": "Person.Ids",
            "format": "use_field_mapping"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @Abyrbalg it's been a long time. I hope you are doing well  Did you get a chance to go through my answer, looking forward to get feedback from you 

Comment: @Abyrbalg if my answer helped you resolve your issue, then please don't forget to upvote and accept the answer as well 

Comment: @Abyrbalg thank u for accepting my answer, can you please upvote the answer as well by clicking on the up arrow beside by answer 